# Confusion in the display of a lineEdit - Qt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv

I have two integer numbers that  I have converted into String to convert them once again to QString (qW and qH).

Their int values are respectively 970 and 938

I want to display their values using the following code that I have thought of:

```
lineEdit_mat->setText(qW + " " + qH);
```

But in the created interface, the displayed result is:
    970 970938

I tried lots of combinations, but no way to display:
    970 938

The whole code:

```
int width=img_crop_mat->width ;
int height=img_crop_mat->height ;
ostringstream convert;
string W, H;
convert << width ;
W=convert.str();
convert << height;
H=convert.str();
QString qH = QString::fromStdString(H);
QString qW= QString::fromStdString(W);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you create `qW` and `qH`?

Comment: QString qH = QString::fromStdString(H);
    QString qW= QString::fromStdString(W);

NB: W and H are the corresponding converted int (string)

Comment: How do you create `H` and `W`?

Comment: @ZeusM how do you define `W` and `H`.  We are checking to see if the problem is within the definitions, or something else.

Comment: Just show *all* code concerning this.

Comment: when you push height in the stream it still contains the previous pushed string so it just concatenates "938" to the previous "970". Add `convert.str("");` before 2nd conversion.

Comment: I have edited my question in which you can find all the code.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're concatenating qW onto qH, can't comfirm this without seeing the code so please post more code for reference but these few lines should work

```
QString qH = QString::number(height);
QString qW = QString::number(width);
lineEdit_mat->setText(qW + " " + qH);
```

Where height and width are your integer values. If this doesn't work please post your code. I haven't tested this but I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

EDIT: Just seen the code as I posted, try my way, easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: Great! The result is the one I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write :

```
lineEdit_mat->setText( QString("%1 %2").arg(width).arg(height) );
```

Comment: width and height are the variables in your code. You have to create them (or replace by img_crop_mat->width and img_crop_mat->height).